# Dynamic memory allocation does not make (making) a buff overflow?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, malloc, buffer-overflow

I have this code for tests purposes

```
char *name;
name = (char *) malloc(21); // 20 char + '\0' byte
printf("Input your name: ");
gets(name);
printf("%s\n", name);
```

If I understood, malloc has allocated 21 bytes of some block memory and I casted to be a char pointer.
I inputed  in my tests some big length strings (more than 21 char) but I did not get a buffer overflow.

What is the concept I am not grasping?

Comment: In fact, sure you had.

Comment: The concept is *undefined behaviour*. The program doesn't have to report any kind of error. It can do whatever it wants.

Comment: @ouah  I did not get any **segmentation fault (core dumped)**

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` to make it a `char` pointer, `void *` is converted to any pointer type without cast.

Comment: @0vid who told you a buffer overflow has to lead to a segmentation fault in all cases?

Comment: Run the code using a memory checker like Valgrind (http://valgrind.org) and see what it tells you.

Comment: @ouah but the program would not crash? I think when they crash it would give a **seg fault** or some error info. For sure I do not know yet what a seg fault is.

Comment: A segfault occurs when the OS detects an access out of what your program was allocated. However, dynamic memory frequently allocates more than what you ask for to fit a fixed page size, so the memory you trample is yours : no segfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A buffer overflow occurs as soon as you write the 22nd character to `name`.  That character is stored in a memory location beyond the storage allocated for `name`.  The effect of overflowing the buffer is *undefined behavior* which has a nasty habit of doing nothing notable especially in a simple application.

Comment: sorry for my computer ignorance but this **undefined behavior** occurred because I do not have any other variable declared in **main** function so it does not take the supposed other variable memory? Or buffers overflow occur and when running a program it does not prompt anything?